# Quick Test Pro (11) not running when computer is locked

Tags: batch-file, qtp

I need to run QTP scripts when I'm not at work. So I'm scheduling (with windows task scheduler), batch files (which calls .vbs files) to call the QTP codes.

They run fine, if the computer is no locked (I have tried with the scheduled taks, and running the .batch directly also).

Even when the computer has been locked for a hour, the QTP scripst run fine.

But if the computer is locked for several hours (for example, if I leave work at 5 pm, and I need to run the scripts after  12 am), the QTP scripts don´t run (neither an error message is popped up, nor QTP in encycled, nor nothing).

Anybody has an idea what need to be done to work this out?

Comment: you need to set your schedule to run whether use is logged on or not.

Answer (score 2):

Directly from [**`UFT help file`**](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/Tr_Lim_Running_TEST.htm), same applies to QTP:

When running UFT tests or components on a local machine, if the computer on which the application is being tested is locked, your test run may fail.

Workaround:
Install UFT on a virtual machine (without a screen saver or lock password), and start or schedule your run session on the virtual machine. Then you can lock your local computer without locking the virtual machine.

Another workaround (*not recommended*):
Play any video in loop in Windows Media Player. This will prevent your machine from get locked automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you can auto schedule the script through the external free software like Auto-Sys.
There you can create jobs to unlock the machine and then run the regression.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use the below utility to keep you system unlocked

https://sumeetkushwah.com/2015/11/07/windows-lock-prevention-utility/

Answer (score 0):

use the below code and save this as a .vbs file(SomeName.vbs)

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do 
    WshShell.SendKeys "{CAPSLOCK}"
    WScript.sleep (1000) '1000 means one second. choose the time of your liking
    WshShell.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}"
Loop
```

Double click the saved vbs file. Your computer will not get locked unless you manually kill the WScript.exe task in your task manager. Use the keys of your choice from here http://www.pctools.com/guides/scripting/detail/149/?act=reference